# Mergesort with an odd arrayList size mixes the numbers up slightly

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, merge, mergesort

Recently I fixed up my mergesort function, and it works perfectly with evenly sized arraylists. However, with odd sized arraylists, it slightly mixes up the results. This is an example:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]> but was: <[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8]>
```

Here is the code:

```java
protected static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergesort(ArrayList<T> list) {
    ArrayList<T> tempList = generateArrayList(list.size());
    mergesort(list, tempList, 0, list.size() - 1);
}

//helper method for merge sort driver
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergesort(ArrayList<T> list, ArrayList<T> tempList, int left, int right) {
    if ((right - left) > insertThreshold) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        mergesort(list, tempList, left, mid);
        mergesort(list, tempList, mid + 1, right);
        merge(list, tempList, left, mid + 1, right);
    } else if ((right - left) <= insertThreshold) {
        insertionSort(list, right, left);
    }
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(ArrayList<T> list, ArrayList<T> tempList, int left, int right, int rEnd) {
    int i = left;//k

    int lNew = left;//i

    int rNew = right;//j
    int lEnd = right - 1;

    while (lNew <= lEnd && rNew <= rEnd) {
        if (list.get(lNew).compareTo(list.get(rNew)) <= 0) {
            tempList.set(i, list.get(lNew));
            i++;
            lNew++;
        } else {
            tempList.set(i, list.get(rNew));
            i++;
            rNew++;
        }
    }
    while (lNew <= lEnd) {
        tempList.set(i, list.get(lNew));
        i++;
        lNew++;
    }

    while (rNew <= rEnd) {
        tempList.set(i, list.get(rNew));
        i++;
        rNew++;
    }
    for (int j = left; j <= rEnd; j++) {
        list.set(j, tempList.get(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to reimplement lEnd without ruining the way the sort works, and I'm not sure what you mean by the second comment.

Comment: I figured out that my insertion sort was off, but now I'm stuck again trying to figure out how to properly set up lEnd so that regardless of the size, it will be able to properly initialize and prevent any element from leaking

Comment: How do you mean by that? What I'm referring to is that, with an arraylist that has an odd set of elements, the sort will be ever so slightly off due to a few misplaced numbers in the finalized array.

Comment: give one example input data for which that happens (I used a list with `2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, randomly shuffled and `insertThreshold` 2 and  3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229503/discussion-between-five-and-user15244370).